# How does the Price/Time Priority Algorithm work?

Tags: algorithm, finance

I'm trying to program a simple FIFO (Price/Time Priority) order matching program, but I'm not too sure if I've got the logic correct:

```
for each unfilled buy order (newest first):
    filter orders by buy price > sell price
    while buy order not filled:
        fill best priced sell order
        if multiple equal cheapest sell orders:
            fill oldest
    if remainder of most recently filled sell order is not 0:
        create new sell order for remainder
```

I've run this on a simulation of 500 buy and sell orders respectively, but to be honest don't have a reference to check whether it's matched orders appropriately - and trying to run through the transactions by hand would be incredibly time consuming. Can anyone confirm I've got this right?

Comment: You need to first fully describe the problem and then your solution to that. You started right away with solution.

Comment: If you don't have any unit tests, then you have a bug :-)

Comment: Is your algorithm for buying or selling? It looks like you're trying to do both.